# Laravel 5.2 does not show bootstrap form

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to ask you about register page, I'm trying to do and I'm new to Laravel.

In my `composer.json` there is this part:

```
require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
},
```

and in app.php :

providers :

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

aliases:

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective
```

How can I display my register form [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsYFl.png)?

but it displays right now [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci5qz.png)

My working register page code:

```
@extends(

    'layouts.masters.main')

    @section('page-content')


    <div class="container">

        @include('layouts.partials.nav')

        <form class="form-signin">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                </label>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>

    </div>
    @stop
```

Comment: I would like to help you but where is the problem?

Comment: just cant change the display . the first image i want it to displayed but it shows the second image i uploaded

Comment: ok where do you have your CSS?

Comment: under project name in public folder

Comment: I assume you have your css under public/css/stylesheet.css

Comment: you can add this in your master layout `<link href="{{asset('css/stylesheet.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">` if that helps let me know so I can leave an answer

Comment: i didnt understand exatly where it is master layout ?:(

Comment: you already extend layouts.masters.main try to open that it is normally under resources\views\layout\masters and it must be names main this is how I read it in the name convention

Comment: in my public/css/ there are bootstrap.css , bootstrap.min.css ,bootstrap-theme.css ,bootstrap-theme.min.css folders

Comment: yes i did but notthing changed still :(

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ sorry for bothering you , may i ask you a quesion about dropdownlist filter?

Comment: Let me hear it please

Comment: i asked it in the site , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204060/laravel-5-2-filter-with-dropdownlist . maybe you can find me a solution

Comment: Hi maytham , sorry to bother you again but before asking a question on the site , i just wanted to ask you about any suggestions . i wanted to add a real time video chat page in my laravel project . Maybe you can give any suggestions or site links for any tutorials about real time video chat that might help .Is there any package for laravel or something else ? Sorry that i bother you :(

Comment: Hi @minchevz it is fine you do not bother, think Laravel is based on PHP, and what you ask for has no relation to Laravel. so we can ask in another word does PHP support realtime video, the answer is NO, you need to use 3rd part real time video service, what you can do is using that service API. Or develop your own system but that need high bandwidth connection and power full servers. all depends on how many users etc. hope that you can use my answer, and please vote if you like my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template needs the css stylesheet.

I assume it is under `public/css/`

if that the case you need to add following line to your blade master layout

```
<link href="{{asset('css/stylesheet.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: you are welcome. if you have fonts, javascript etc you can use the same way `<script src="{{asset('js/somejavascript.js')}}"></script>`