# Laravel 5.2 filter with dropdownlist

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I want to make drop-down list filtering.

I have a web page, that shown some post with title and categories.

The page has a drop-down in `nav.blade.php`. I dynamically generate drop-down from categories table. But when I select an item of drop-down (for example a category name) I want page to show me the posts only of that category. Also I have created the Category and Posts model and set the relationships. I can see all posts on my main page but can't filter content with drop-down list.

What I am doing wrong? and how can I solve this issue?

My nav.blade:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>@foreach($categories as $category)
                <a href="{{URL::route('home',$category->id)}}">
                    <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                </a>
            @endforeach
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I have corrected your question please read it and confirm, because your previous formulation was not understandable?

Comment: ok thank you so much

Comment: no problem, you should have told me that the following solution was working since I spend some time to make for you :) good luck

Comment: i know but i just figured it out :( sorry mate . i thought havent started it yet :( im really sorry

Comment: no problem, good luck any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would get you started:

Assuming you have a route like:

```
Route::get('/{category_id}', ['as'=>'home', 'uses'=>'PostController@show']);
```

In the `PostController@show` method:

```
public function show($category_id)
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $selected_category = Category::with('posts')->where('id', $category_id)->first();
    $posts = $selected_category->posts;

    return redirect()->back()->with(compact('posts', 'categories'));
}
```

You can change the redirect location.

Comment: i got such a error :BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2177:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::posts()

Comment: Did you set your relationships in Post and Category models?

Comment: for Category model: public function  posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post');
    } and for the user model : public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
    }

Comment: also for Post model : public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
    }

Comment: Is your relationsips are working well? Have you tried the eager loading?

Comment: yes my main page every post was showing . but  i couldnt dropdown list filtering

Comment: I mean what happend when you do `Post::with('category')->all()`

Comment: Builder::all() error . didnt work . i think i miss something

Comment: now i had this error : Undefined variable: categories (View: E:\programfiles\xampp\htdocs\deneme\resources\views\layouts\partials\nav.blade.php)

Comment: You have to pass the ` $categories` also along with this method.

Comment: nothing changed but it doesnt show error. just when i select a category , it still shows all my posts on the page

Comment: i figured it out mate . i used : "->get()" function instead of ->first() . for first function i get errors i dont know why . and controller show():
public function show($category_id)
    {

        $posts=Post::where('category_id',$category_id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();

        $categories = Category::all();

        return view('home',compact('posts', 'categories'));
    }